# Reference request: definition of Sobolev space on manifolds using positive elliptic operator

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-operators

I've been reading a paper "Schatten classes on compact manifolds: Kernel conditions" by Delgado and Ruzhansky (https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6158).

In the paper, the authors define the Sobolev space $H^\mu(M)$ on a closed manifold $M$ in the following way:

$H^\mu(M)$ is the space of all distributions $f\in D'(M)$ such that $(I+P)^{\frac{\mu}{\nu}}f\in L^2(M)$ where $P$ is a positive elliptic operator of order $\nu$. Also, this characterisation is independent of the choice of operator $P$.

It is difficult to understand the paper without understanding of the above definition. But I only know basic definition of Sobolev space for $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I learned that from Folland's real analysis book long time ago). Also, I have no background on the elliptic operator for manifolds (I only know that Laplace-Beltrami operator is elliptic).

So, I'm looking for any good books/papers explaining the above definition of Sobolev spaces on manifolds. I tried some googleing but the books I found were not using the above definition.

Comment: The toy model is the torus $\mathbb R^n/\mathbb Z^n$, where you can take$$Pf:=\sqrt{-\Delta}f = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z^n} |n|\hat{f}(n)e^{2\pi i n\cdot x}. $$Here, $\hat{f}(n)$ denotes the Fourier coefficient. I recommend not spending too much time with this definition. I found that it is better to just work with it, instead of trying to make sense of the many different versions of it you find around.

Comment: A good book dealing with this topic is Nonlinear analysis on manifolds: Sobolev Spaces and Inequalities, written by E. Hebey. I guess that the definition you wrote is a consequence of a result known as elliptic regularity, following Hebey's definitions.

Comment: You may also need a book explaining the concept of pseudo-differential operators, I suggest Sogge's book Fourier integrals in Classical analysis.